# turn coherent string into individual characters

Tags: regular-expressions, text

I have a text with a number of coherent strings, e.g.:

```
ax923fasd
asidna1
xxa008
```

Is there a quick way to convert these so that there be a space between each of them, i.e.:

```
a x 9 2 3 f a s d
a s i d n a 1
x x a 0 0 8
```

Comment: Is your text in a buffer, or is it a string object?

Comment: If this is text in a buffer, do you want to do this interactively (via command) or in Lisp code?

Comment: text is in a buffer; would like to do it interactively; phils answer down below solved it nicely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of ways you could do that.

Assuming this is text in a buffer, a simple regexp-based approach is to use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `replace-regexp` to replace `.` with `\&` (n.b. that's <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>&</kbd><kbd>SPC</kbd>) to replace each non-newline character with itself followed by a space.

As that does match the final character of each non-blank line, that *will* introduce a space at the end of those lines, which you might wish to clean up with `delete-trailing-whitespace` or similar.

A fancier interactive regexp replacement which doesn't append the trailing space would be:

`\,(concat \& (if (eolp) "" " "))`